# MySQL: If the end of a string looks like 'BV' UPDATE

Tags: mysql, if-statement, substring

```
UPDATE company
IF SUBSTRING(company_name, LENGTH(company_name)-3, LENGTH(company_name)) = ' BV'
THEN SET company_name = SUBSTRING(company_name,1,LENGTH(company_name)-3);
END IF;
```

I'm getting a syntax error and don't know where to look, any help would be appriciated!
What I'm trying to do is if the end of a string looks like ' BV' UPDATE the column.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use a `where` clause instead of `IF`:

```
UPDATE company 
SET company_name = SUBSTRING(company_name,1,LENGTH(company_name)-3)
where SUBSTRING(company_name, LENGTH(company_name)-3, LENGTH(company_name)) = ' BV'
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an error in your IF statement:

```
IF SUBSTRING(company_name, LENGTH(company_name)-3, LENGTH(company_name)) = ' BV'
```

Should be

```
IF SUBSTRING(company_name, LENGTH(company_name)-3, 3) = ' BV'
```

An easier way of going about this would be to use a where clause and a like comparison.

```
UPDATE company
SET company_name = SUBSTRING(company_name, 1, LENGTH(company_name)-3)
WHERE company_name like '% BV';
```